# How to import ActivityLifecycle.zip from developer.android.com into Android Studio?

Tags: android

I'm going through the Android Developer Training, but I'm currently stuck [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). I can't figure out how to import the [sample project](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/ActivityLifecycle.zip) without gradle breaking. These are the results when I use `File > New > Import Project`

```
/path/to/activity-lifecycle$ ./gradlew assembleDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find target with hash string 'android-14' in: /home/user/Android/Sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.273 secs
```

*EDIT: Android Studio 1.5.1, Gradle 2.8, Java 1.8.0_65, Debian 8.2*

**EDIT2:** Make sure to update `activity-lifecycle/app/build.gradle` not `activity-lifecycle/build.gradle`

Comment: can you post your gradle file?

Comment: @sha i posted `build.gradle`, should i also post `settings.gradle` ?

Comment: Can you post `build.gradle` on the App level. You posted top level gradle

Comment: @sha oh wow, didn't even realize there were multiple build files... just changed the app level one and it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In build.grandle , make sure you have

`compileSdkVersion 22`

If it's still not work open the "SDK Manager" and install the SDK.

For shorten:

Open 'Module setting', Goto 'properties' tab, Choose build version and target.